# cakephp inside a subdirectory

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, subdirectory

I have a problem with cakephp, I can't find a way to get cakephp working in a subdirectory. I have a webpage that resides at `www.example.com` and I want to have cakephp application on `www.example.com/cake`. `www.example.com` is a virtual host and `cake` is it's subdirectory where all of the cake files and directories are stored.
The problem is that when I go to `www.example.com/cake` it requests a CakeController and has no stylesheets loaded.
When I go to `www.example.com/cake/users/register` (= `UsersController::register()` ) it shows the right site but again without CSS.

So I need two things...to get `www.example.com/cake` to display the home page and to get the stylesheets loadedd.

Don't you know how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/915/Advanced-Installation) in the book and make the appropriate changes in `/app/webroot/index.php`?

**Edit:**

> The problem is that when I go to
>   www.example.com/cake it requests a
>   CakeController and has no stylesheets
>   loaded.

This seems to indicate that you have the wrong .htaccess in your site's root (www, htdocs ,public_html or whatever) as it's trying to process the request into the CakePHP structure.

It should **not** look like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Why don't you make life easy for yourself and put CakePHP in the root and move the page(s) that reside at `www.example.com` into app/webroot. That way it'll behave exactly as you want, i.e:

`www.example.com/staticPage.html` - displays the static page.

`www.example.com/users` - displays the users index

Files in webroot are served exactly as if they were in the site's root. Think of the css and javascript files.

Comment: Well the changes were not necessary, since the paths lead to the right directories

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your mod_rewrite is not enable in Apache on your hosting account. Check with your host. Another possible problem described below:

Did you change the paths in webroot/index.php?

You need to adjust the paths in that file to point to the Cake core files folder based on your hosting providers directory path.

For example,

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) { 
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'home' . DS .'w3dev' . DS . 'public_html' . DS . 'clients' . DS . 'folderName' . DS . 'remote' . DS . 'v1.1' . DS .  'cake'); 
}
```

And

```
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))). DS . 'v1.1' . DS . 'app'); 
}
```

The above all depends on your directory on your hosting server account. As your host for your root path data, so you can point it accordingly.

Comment: well, my `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` is `/var/www/example/cake` which is ok, `APP_DIR` is `app` which is fine too i guess and `ROOT` is same asi core indluce path: `/var/www/example/cake`.

Comment: I don't understand this - at the top you say you have the cake app under cake. Here you seem to be implying that the cake app is under example.

Comment: Leo, cake and app are in the same directory (not sub of one another). My example was probably poor, but it was just to give some guidance : )

Comment: the directory structure is following: `/var/www/example/cake/app` and `/var/www/example/cake/cake` ... maybe it was unlucky to put the whole thing into `cake` directory, but from now on, you should understand what I am trying to achieve

Comment: So your CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH should be: /var/www/example/cake/ and your APP_DIR should be: cake/app, but you need to use the same structure that I have laid out with the . DS . separators etc.

Comment: Sorry OldWest, my comment was responding to Elwhis' comment - I should have made that clear. Your (OldWest's) example was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Cake, but it is almost certainly some sort of path issue. Verify that the path to your stylesheets is accurate.

I know that some frameworks will use a base_url() function(or something similarly named) that returns a config value, you should check your config to ensure that the base URL is set properly.