# The correct way to set CakePHP base URL

Tags: php, url, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.5

My CakePHP site resides at `http://localhost/somepath/`. How should I set up CakePHP so that everything works?

I tried adding add the line

```
RewriteBase  /somepath/
```

to `.htaccess` and `app/webroot/.htaccess`. There's no other way I can make URL rewriting work (otherwise, I always get a 404 when accessing the site). This solution works, but breaks routing when used from a CLI. For example, when I use

```
Router::url(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 3), true);
```

in a Shell, I get `http://localhost/posts/view/3` instead of `http://localhost/somepath/posts/view/3`.

So in addition to changing `.htaccess`, I also tried setting `App.fullBaseUrl` in `core.php`, like this:

```
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'http://localhost/somepath');
```

This way, I get correct URLs in Shells, but not on web pages ­– e.g. using the same `Router::url` call as above, I get `http://localhost/somepath/somepath/posts/view/3`.

Comment: See my answer here: [installing cakephp 2.0.0 in a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957072/installing-cakephp-2-0-0-in-a-subdirectory/11957690#11957690)

Comment: Thanks @Dave, but as I'm getting an error (404) from Apache and not from Cake with the _unchanged_ `.htaccess`, I guess there is a problem with URL rewriting, and not Cake configuration.

Comment: Yes. As I said, it works if I set the `RewriteBase`.

Answer (score 3):

Should the `/somepath/` be visible in the url or do you try to hide this subfolder in the url?

Have you tried to add `RewriteBase /somepath/` in all 3 htaccess files?

```
/yourcakedir/.htaccess
/yourcakedir/app/.htaccess
/yourcakedir/app/webroot/.htaccess
```

and then in

```
/yourcakedir/app/config/bootstrap.php
```

add

```
Configure::write('App.base','');
```

You can also add

```
Configure::write('App.base','/');
```

but this can bring up double slashes in some cases, because your htaccess RewriteBase already ends with a slash.

If you set the `App.base` you shouldn't need this line in your `core.php`:

```
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'http://localhost/somepath');
```

Comment: The core.php file says you should either be using .htaccess or App.baseUrl/fulLBaseUrl, not both.