# Error in Cakephp 2.8.4 as sub-directory inside a core PHP website

Tags: php, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.0, subdirectory, file-not-found

I am getting the error(`mysite.com/cake-284/users/login`):

> 404 - File or directory not found.

-after uploading the Cakephp 2.8.4 sub-directory to my PHP website in the live host.

But the subdirectory root(`mysite.com/cake-284`) shows:

> 500 - Internal server error.

The site is running fine in the localhost by the **wamp server (PHP Version 5.5.12)**.

I believe this is the problem of my **`.htaccess`** file(s). After searching for a solution, I found [Set up CakePHP in a subdirectory; Wordpress is installed in the root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947396/set-up-cakephp-in-a-subdirectory-wordpress-is-installed-in-the-root), and [cakephp inside a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928131/cakephp-inside-a-subdirectory). But these didn't help.

There is no  **`.htaccess`** file in the root.

**mysite.com/cake-284/app/webroot/.htaccess** :

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`

**mysite.com/cake-284/app/.htaccess** :

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

**mysite.com/cake-284/.htaccess** :

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

**Cakephp 2.8.6, PHP Version: 5.5.35**

I don't know if there is anything else to do with the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Edit .htaccess with you sub directory

mysite.com/cake-284/app/webroot/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cake-284
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

mysite.com/cake-284/app/.htaccess :

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /cake-284
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

mysite.com/cake-284/.htaccess :

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /cake-284
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you are getting 500 - Internal server error.please check the file permission . file and folder permission please check

Comment: You can also debug this by create any file like test.php in that subfolder and access it.[HITS]/cake-284/test.php      if you are able to access then need check file permission of cakephp

Comment: Read my question. `500 - Internal server error.` is only for `mysite.com/cake-284`

Comment: I have a working `cake-284/phpinfo.php` and write permission is allowed for `app\tmp\cache` and all files under this directory.